# iOS image size when taking snapshot and save into camera roll

Tags: iphone, ios

I took a screenshot and saved image into camera roll, and set this image into lock screen.
but image size is 640*940 in iPhone 4. How can I make it 640*960 without any distortion? I guess status bar has some height.

```
CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can go about setting the image size...

Fist you can set your own frame for the screenshot:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 960);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
```

This will take the size you want.  Keep in mind that if your screen size is say 320 x 480 you will get a returned image of 640 x 960 but will be white space outside of your actual screenshot range.

Another approach would be to find the area you want from an object such as an image view:

```
UIImageView *imageview;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageview.frame.size);
```

Again this will return what you want but anything outside of the actual screen size will be filled with white space.